# What's mean 'fb' and 'b' in Jena rules //OWL, RDFS

Tags: rdf, jena, owl, rdfs, jena-rules

[image]

There is a Jena rules 
I don't know prefix b and fb.
What different things each OWL and RDFS files?

PS.
download URL is 
https://jena.apache.org/download/index.cgi and click jena-2.11.1-source-release.zip (MD5, PGP)

rules dir -> jena-core/src/main/resources/etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*.rules` files are files with rules used by all the different [Jena reasoners](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/).

See the comments in the headers of the files. For example for the [owl-fb.rules](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ghillairet/p2/e62531429e5412038e753de2850eb65f685a206f/jena/org.apache.jena/etc/owl-fb.rules) file it is:

> OWL rule set v0.3
>    This rule set is designed to implement owl(f)lite using the hybrid
>    rule system (mixture of forward and backward chaining). It differs
>    from earlier versions by more consistently sticking to instance reasoning
>    by being design to work with the LP backward engine.
>
> It includes an experimental forward version of the equality reasoning which
>    not yet scalable.

So `b` stands for `backward chaining`, `f` for `forward chaining`, and `fb` for a combination of the two.